# Printing tab (\t) characters in VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use iPython in the integrated terminal in VS Code on Linux, `print('col1\tcol2')` prints `col1    col2`, where the separation is 4 spaces instead of a tab character. Running the same command inside an external GNOME terminal correctly prints the tab character.

Is there a setting to change the behaviour of the integrated terminal so that it correctly prints tabs?

This is an issue for me because I'm copying and pasting the terminal output into a google sheets spreadsheet. Tabs are recognized as column separators whereas spaces are not. (I know this is an inelegant way to do things.)

**VS Code info**

- Version: 1.30.1
- Commit: dea8705087adb1b5e5ae1d9123278e178656186a
- Date: 2018-12-18T18:07:32.870Z
- Electron: 2.0.12
- Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
- Node.js: 8.9.3
- V8: 6.1.534.41
- OS: Linux x64 4.9.0-4-amd64

**Python info**

- Python 3.5.3
- IPython 7.0.1

Comment: I had the same question, also because of Google Sheets. Found this related Github Issue https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/734. It seems like VS Code does not support this.

Comment: what exactly do you expect to see? how many equivalents of a space character do you expect to see? do you expect tab stops to be aligned to a grid?

Comment: @starball We expect to see tabs. Instead, we see 4 spaces!

Answer (score 0):

VS Code's integrated terminal uses [xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js). This is the subject of issue ticket [Support rendering of tab characters in terminal #734](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/734). It's closed as "as-designed", for the reason explained in [this comment](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/734#issuecomment-347506518) and also [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/29523#issuecomment-353696492). Quoting Daniel Imms (one of the VS Code maintainers):

> tab is not a printable character in a terminal but rather repositions in the cursor,

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters

I honestly don't completely understand the logic. I'm just trying to present it as faithfully as I can.